# How to put a parenthesis at the end of a line

Tags: python, duckyscript

I decided to try to do a code to automatically convert a ducky code into a python code (at least at a simple level), and the first thing I wanted to do was changing the `STRING` in the ducky code to python using pynput. The equivalent of `STRING` is `keyboard.type()`, defining keyboard as `pynput.keyboard.Controller()`.

So, for example, the code should turn this:

```
STRING hello
STRING how are you?
```

Into this:

```
keyboard.type("hello")
keyboard.type("how are you?")
```

What I've tried was this:

```
ducky=input("Introduce your ducky code... \n")
py=ducky.replace("STRING", '''keyboard.type("''')
```

That code works, but it doesn't put the quotation marks and the parenthesis at the end of each line, and I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me?
Also, I'm a beginner, and I tried to use `.replace` for this because I know how it works, but if there is something better to use in this case, please, tell me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your string into lines, then add the `'keyboard.type("'` and the `'")'` to it, and finally rejoin the lines.

```py
py=[]
for line in ducky.splitlines():
    print(line)
    if line.startswith("STRING "):
        py.append('keyboard.type("'+line[7:]+'")')
    else:
        py.append(line)

py="\n".join(py)
```